# Move home directory to another directory in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: directory

I want to move my present home directory to another directory in my virtual-box ubuntu 12.04 distro. Here is what I want:

Right now my present home directory is located at `/home/jhon`.

But I want to change it to `/home/users/jhon`

How do I do that? So that when I type `$HOME`, it should point to `/home/users/jhon`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo usermod -d /home/users -m
```

should move all files form your old home (/home/) to your new home (/home/users/) and update all files that need to be updated (like `/etc/passwd`).